# imfdatapy: Pulling data from IMF API in Python does not work

Tags: python

I am simply trying to reproduce the code from Irina Klein's imfdatapy-package in Python (https://github.com/Economic-and-Financial-Data-Discovery/imfdatapy)

```
pip install imfdatapy

from imfdatapy.imf import *

ifs = IFS(search_terms=["gross domestic product"], countries=["US"], period='Q',
start_date="2000", end_date="2022")


df=ifs.download_data()
```

Result:
 `OSError: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: '..\out'`

Actually, I am stuck. I simply wanted to recreate something that has been done previousley with success.

Comment: Error says there is no such folder "out" in the directory above of where this script is running. You could create such a folder with `os.mkdir()`